# How to use elasticsearch and autocomplete jquery with suggested array

Tags: jquery, elasticsearch, autocomplete

I am using elasticsearch with laravel 5 :

Done lots of search and read article at qbox and elasticsearch about [ As you type result ] But i want to show result only from suggested_tags and jquery autocomplete shows only that suggested tag from array not all.

I have lots of suggestion text in array filed elasticsearch named suggested_tags and you can see in picture there are lots of. I am trying to search through and using this query :

[Showing Result In Sense kibana plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gySQ.png)

```
GET yourservice/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "suggested_tags": {
        "query": "car",
        "type": "phrase_prefix",
        "operator": "and",
        "fuzziness": 1.1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this one showing wrong result and showing multiple result with car near about 17 same repeat.

if use this query :

```
GET yourservice/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "suggested_tags": "car"
    }
  }
}
```

Result count is 2 but same example :

Jquery autocomplete shows :

Automobile and Car
Automobile and Car

In curl query shows two result but in laravel search with jquery autocomplete shows multiple same result look in image.

[Wrong multiple result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/995Cw.png)

I am just confused why elasticsearch different result and not result as i type.

here is jQuery Code :

```
$(function() {
            $("#search").autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                    var wildcard = { "name": "*" + request.term.toLowerCase() + "*" };
                    var postData = {
                        "query": { "wildcard": wildcard },
                        "fields": ["name", "title"]
                    };
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/api/search?query=" + $("#search").val(),
                        type: "GET",
                        success: function(data) {
                            response($.map(data.hits.hits, function(item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item._source.name,
                                    id: item._source.title
                                }
                            }));
                        },
                    });
                },
                minLength: 1
            })
        });
```

and Query using with laravel :

```
$params = [
            'index' => 'yourservice',
            'type' => 'categories',
            'body' => [
                "query" => [
                    "match" => [
                        "suggested_tags" => \Input::get("query")
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi had same problem but i am using [Easy Auto Complete](https://github.com/pawelczak/EasyAutocomplete) jQuery Plugin. Just because it's easy to use and need to write less code and more events also you can use jquery autocomplete with this.

Your question is autocomplete with suggested array as in image you uploaded right ?

I think best part to use multiple suggestion from array you defined with this code :

```
"terms" => [
  "suggested_tags" => [
    // You need multiple values so use php string explode function then put variable here.
  ]
]
```

Don't forget to write above code in query array.

You can read more about terms here : [Elastic Search Terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

After that you can use highlight the field :

```
"highlight" => [
  "fields" => [
    "suggested_tags" => [
      "fragment_size" => 40
    ]
  ]
]
```

Above code will highlight text with [em] tag by default and you change that too.

As i saw you have too many suggestion tags in array and if you want the suggestion you need to loop through all.

Right now :

```
success: function(data) {
  response($.map(data.hits.hits, function(item) {
    return {
      label: item._source.name,
      id: item._source.title
    }
  }));
},
```

Need to be somthing like :

```
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  return result[i];
}
```

I can help you more if your question will more understandable to me or i can fix it by access as you mentioned.